# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.quartz.Scheduler.getTrigger(Lorg/quartz/TriggerKey;)Lorg/quartz/Trigger;

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

***pom.xml***

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version><!-- <version>2.2.1</version>-->
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

***context.xml***

```
<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">ClusterScheduler</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <!-- 线程池配置 -->
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">20</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">5</prop>
            <!-- JobStore 配置 -->
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>

            <!-- 集群配置 -->
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">15000</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.maxMisfiresToHandleAtATime">1</prop>

            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">120000</prop>

            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">QRTZ_</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="schedulerName" value="ClusterScheduler" />

    <!--必须的，QuartzScheduler 延时启动，应用启动完后 QuartzScheduler 再启动 -->
    <property name="startupDelay" value="30" />

    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContextKey" />

    <!--可选，QuartzScheduler 启动时更新己存在的Job，这样就不用每次修改targetObject后删除qrtz_job_details表对应记录了 -->
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />

    <!-- 设置自动启动 -->
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />

    <!--<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz.properties" />-->
</bean>
```

ERROR

> ContextLoader@(ContextLoader.java:331):Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'scheduleJobInit': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.quartz.Scheduler.getTrigger(Lorg/quartz/TriggerKey;)Lorg/quartz/Trigger;
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at

Comment: can you please post your complete pom? you might have dependency conflicts

Comment: i hide some conficts what unused ,it's success,thanks